# How do I get SOSL WITH HIGHLIGHT in Apex?

Tags: apex, sosl

Is it possible to get the highlight field from a SOSL search within apex?

For example:

```
List<List<Contact>> results = [
  FIND {text} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, Name) WITH HIGHLIGHT
];
```

Is there a way to get the highlight field containing the `<mark>text</mark>` tags? For example:

```
contact.get('highlight.Name');
```

Or is this only available when executing SOSL using the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is available only in SOAP api and REST api as mentioned in the official documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_with_highlight.htm) in Supported APIs section:

> The WITH HIGHLIGHT clause in SOSL is supported in SOAP API and REST
>   API.